# Decrypt message using Proxy Re-encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs, encryption-asymmetric

I am new to encryption and am using a Node JS library 
[recrypt-js](https://github.com/yjjnls/recrypt-js/)  to perform Proxy Re-encryption using CryptoJS. In the example given there is a message "test data" that is to be encrypted, but the issue is that I am unable to decrypt the encrypted message back to the original text.

In the following code:

```
...

let obj = PRE.encryptData(pk_A, "test data")
    console.log(obj)
    let rk = PRE.generateReEncrytionKey(sk_A, pk_B);
    PRE.reEncryption(rk, obj)

    let decryptData = PRE.decryptData(sk_B, obj)
    console.log(decryptData)
```

The output for decryptData is showing an object containing an array of digits. How can I successfully output the original text? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

decryptData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).